# Creating a JavaScript literal object – within XPath 2.0

Tags: javascript, json, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

**Background:** I need to use XSLT 2.0 within the web browser to execute another XSLT 2.0 transform - this is to be used in a test-driver for the XSLT processor. The JavaScript API for the processor lets you build a literal *command* object that is passed as a parameter to a *run* function to execute the transform.

Building the command object is quite straightforward from JavaScript, but from XSLT I need to use built-in JavaScript extensions with user-defined JavaScript functions to convert XSLT data into a JavaScript object.  There's an issue in that XPath 2.0 works with sequences of items, but sequences of sequences are not permitted. The approach I’m currently using is shown in the following XSLT snippet which declares a variable, *cmd*:

[image: XSLT code to create a JavaScript object]

The equivalent JavaScript is shown below, for reference:

```
var cmd= {
            initialTemplate: initialTemplate,
            stylesheet:      stylesheet,
            source:          'uk-maps.xml',
            parameters:      {
                                            country:    'UK',
                                            city:       'Cheltenham',
                                            color:       [28, 329, 767]
                             }
};
```

When crossing into JavaScript, the XSLT processor converts the sequence to an array of JavaScript objects. The user-defined JavaScript function *js:object* processes the array and creates properties for the odd items and asigns property values from the corresponding even items.  The *js:object* function can be called recursively to assign JavaScript objects to properties of the new object. My other workaround is the user-defined js:array function, this wraps an XPath sequence in a JavaScript object to allow it to be embedded as a sequence item. The *js:object* function must detect and unwrap these js:array objects.

**So, the question is:** this is one way to build a JavaScript literal object from within XSLT 2.0, but it involves some workarounds that might no suit everyone. What other methods could be used? Perhaps I should use an existing JavaScript library function that converts XML to a literal JavaScript object? Would XSLT 3.0 maps (not yet available in this processor) provide a better solution? What progress has been made on the proposed JSON / XSLT compatibility features? Would it be better if *js:object* and *js:array* were extension functions built into the processor?

Comment: Please don't dwell on the specifics of the API in this question - it was just put forwards as an example of XSLT / JSON interoperability - possibly not an ideal one.

Comment: This all can be done in pure XSLT -- why have you decided that extension functions should be used?

Comment: @Dimitre So how do I create a JavaScript object with arrays and property values that are literal objects in pure XSLT? Can you give a simple example - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Dimitre I think your comment is related to the fact that I've used an XSLT command object as an example, please just think of that as data that needs to be passed to some library function in an external JavaScript library referenced from the same HTML page as that which 'hosts' the XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Phil, You create it as a string -- then JS needs just to use its `eval()` function on this string -- as described here: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @Dimitre Yes, sorry, I should have made it clearer in the question body (though it is in the title) that I need the functionality of a JavaScript literal object, rather than a JSON string. The example shows references to objects that could be XML document nodes (like $stylesheet) - this wouldn't work as a simple JSON string inside an eval() function.

Comment: Phil, it would be useful then if you could provide a complete example: inputs and desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make the thing complete in the space available with the existing example which is contrived as it is to keep things simple - this is a test-driver for a comprehensive test suite.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is one approach to such kind of task**:

Given the following XML document:

```
<t xmlns:js="js:aux">
 <initialTemplate>
   <js:var>initialTemplate</js:var>
 </initialTemplate>
 <stylesheet>
   <js:var>stylesheet</js:var>
 </stylesheet>
 <source>uk-maps.xml</source>
 <parameters>
  <js:object>
          <country>UK</country>
          <city>Cheltenham</city>
          <colours>
            <js:array>
                   <js:num>28</js:num>
                   <js:num>329</js:num>
                   <js:num>767</js:num>
           </js:array>
          </colours>
  </js:object>
 </parameters>
</t>
```

**this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:js="js:aux">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   }
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(self::js:*)]">
   <xsl:variable name="vNotLast" select="exists(following-sibling::*[1])"/>

         <xsl:sequence select="name(), ':&#9;'"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>

         <xsl:sequence select="','[$vNotLast], '&#xA;'"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::js:*)]/text()">
  <xsl:sequence select='concat("&apos;", ., "&apos;")'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="js:object">
  {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  }
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="js:array">
  [
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  ]
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="js:array/*">
  <xsl:next-match/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNotLast" select="exists(following-sibling::*[1])"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="','[$vNotLast]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces**:

```
  {
    initialTemplate :   initialTemplate, 
 stylesheet :   stylesheet, 
 source :    'uk-maps.xml' , 
 parameters :   
  {
    country :    'UK' , 
 city :  'Cheltenham' , 
 colours :  
  [
    28,329,767
  ]


  }


   }
```

Then this result needs just to be fed to the Javascript `eval()` function.

Comment: +1 because I like the portability of the solution you suggest. One possible addition to this (though it would need more than an eval() call to do the necessary parse): there could be a js:node element also that could have the necessary lexical XML, if this were required. I'm waiting to see if there's an answer that tells me that this is a common pattern and that a 'standard' schema is already being used.

Comment: In this answer, the output produced from the transform will not work inside an eval() function because there are unresolved references to *initialTemplate* and *stylesheet*.

Comment: @pgfearo: Yes, And these aren't provided in the question. My guess is that the values of referenced variables ill be converted to JSON before this transformation takes place.

Comment: The terms JSON and JavaScript literal object are often used interchangeably - but here it's a JavaScript literal I would like, (as stated in the title) not JSON. This will give most flexibility for the tests. I think I'll stick with the extension functions I'm using and wait until XPath 3.0 maps are available (see my answer below) before going for a more standards-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

My current thinking is to initially use the original solution with XPath 2.0 outlined in the question. Then, when XPath 3.0 maps are supported by the processor the new [map constructor](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/expressions/xpath30maps.xml) could be used, so the equivalent code would be:

```
<xsl:variable
name="cmd"
select="
map {
       'initialTemplate' := $initialTemplate;
       'stylesheet'      := $stylesheet;
       'source'          := 'uk-maps.xml';
       'parameters'      := map {
                                    'country'  := 'UK';
                                    'city'     := 'Cheltenham';
                                    'color'    := (28, 329, 767);

                                };
};
"/>
```

I'm assuming the map can handle sequences as value items and it can also include other maps as value items, so the call to the JavaScript function would then be the only non-standard part:

```
<xsl:variable name="result" as="document-node()" select="js:run($cmd)"/>
```